# Fix JS object replacing/encoding of strings?

Tags: javascript, json

I have an object with a value that has spaces in it, and it gets replaced with an encoded string, like:

`alldata["test"]` will return "Long+name"
or something like
`alldata["test"]` will return "%BLong+name%B"

when it's set by using

`alldata["test"] = "Long name"`  (or "[Long name]") via a series of code.

Am I missing something? I don't think using `$.toEvalJSON` is the right way to go because I haven't transformed the object into JSON. I'd rather not do a string.replace either because I'd have to capture every possible type of input that is encoded.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is related to the fact that I failed to mention that the object was being assigned the string as a result of a `.serialize()` command. Hence a `urldecode()` will work perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

If your question is how to remove the encoding, you could always use

```
unescape(s)
```

See [Escape and Unescape Functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Guide/Predefined_Functions/escape_and_unescape_Functions)